# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nn_pruning.modules.quantization'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

Goal: install `nn_pruning`.

Kernel: `conda_pytorch_p36`. I performed Restart & Run All.

It seems to recognise the `optimize_model` import, but not other functions. Even though they are from the same `nn_pruning` library.

```
pip install nn_pruning | pip install -U nn_pruning
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: nn_pruning in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.6 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nn_pruning) (1.8.1+cpu)
Requirement already satisfied: transformers>=4.3.0 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nn_pruning) (4.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nn_pruning) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.24 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nn_pruning) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.24->nn_pruning) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.24->nn_pruning) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.24->nn_pruning) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.24->nn_pruning) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch>=1.6->nn_pruning) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torch>=1.6->nn_pruning) (3.10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.1.0 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.27 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (4.62.3)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sacremoses in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (0.0.46)
Requirement already satisfied: tokenizers<0.11,>=0.10.1 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (0.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.12.17 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (2021.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from packaging>=20.0->transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (1.26.5)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sacremoses->transformers>=4.3.0->nn_pruning) (1.16.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

```py
import functools
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch 

#from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering

from nn_pruning.inference_model_patcher import optimize_model
from nn_pruning.modules.quantization import prepare_static, quantize  # !
```

Traceback:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nn_pruning.modules.quantization'
```

Comment: I guess the problem is a missing `__init__.py` file under `nn_pruning.modules`.

Comment: `pip uninstall nn_pruning`: `Y`, `pip install nn_pruning` and changing Kernel all didn't help.

Comment: Tested downloading and building locally. The `nn_pruning.modules.quantization` is not existing entirely. Got a couple of unexpected behavior (skipping here) and proposed modifications in this [PR](https://github.com/huggingface/nn_pruning/pull/31).

Comment: Would it be possible to `pip install` a **stable version**? @deponovo How might I experiment with different versions myself? Is there a list of versions online? I can do this for each of my HuggingFace problems.

Comment: To install a given known version, say `x.y.z`, with `pip` you can `pip install <package>==x.y.z`. [Seek the docs here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/). BTW, there is no such thing as an official `stable` in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [Issue](https://github.com/huggingface/nn_pruning/pull/31) has since been approved to amend this.